# cert-manager: let's encrypt refuses ACME account

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I followed the [cert-manager tutorial](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/) to enable tls in my **k3s cluster**. So I modified the letsencrypt-staging issuer file to look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
    acme:
        # The ACME server URL
        server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
        # Email address used for ACME registration
        email: mail@example.com
        # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
        privateKeySecretRef:
            name: letsencrypt-staging
        # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
        solvers:
        - http01:
            ingress:
                class: traefik
```

but when I deploy it, I get the error  `Failed to verify ACME account: Get "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": read tcp 10.42.0.96:45732->172.65.46.172:443: read: connection reset by peer`. But thats only with the staging clusterIssuer. The production example from te tutorial works flawlessly. I resacherd this error and it seems to be somthing with the kubernetes dns but I don't know how to test the dns or any other way to figure this error out.

---

Tested the kubernetes DNS and it is up and running, so it must be an error with cert-manager,especially because the `prod` certificates status says `Ready=True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like I ran into a let's encrypt limit. After waiting for a day, the certificate now works